# Send blade template mail with mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, mailgun, laravel-mail

I am trying to send mail with Mailgun. If I write this:

```
$mg = Mailgun::create('xxxx');
        $mg->messages()->send('xxxx', [
            'from' => 'dmt.akyol@gmail.com',
            'to' => 'dmt.akyol@gmail.com',
            'subject' => 'Your Link To Login!',
            'text' => 'hello',
        ]);
```

it works  but I want to send a view (blade) and I don't know how to do.

My code is:

```
public function build(array $customer)
{
  return view('link')->with([
    'customer'=> $customer,
  ]);
}
public function sendContactForm(array $customer)
{
  $aaa=$this->build($customer);
  $mg = Mailgun::create('xxxxxx')

  $mg->messages()->send('xxxx'), [
    'from' => $customer['customerEmail'],
    'to' => '   dmt.akyol@gmail.com',
    'subject' => 'Contact Message',
    'html' => $aaa,
  ]);
}
```

This does not work when I write `html` or `text`.

What should I do?

Comment: There you go... removed the downvote.

Comment: i just added sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `->render()` to your build call to store the contents of the view as a string:

```
public function build(array $customer)
{
  return view('link')->with([
    'customer'=> $customer,
  ])->render();
}
```